# Wordpress Application Passwords not authorizing

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to test the wp json rest api using application passwords on the /wp-json/wp/v2/users endpoint.

Note that I can use various json rest api endpoints that don't require authentication, such as retrieving tags, but not for things like users and drafts.

When I try to load drafts or list users I'm unable to get past a json response like this:

```
{
    "code": "rest_user_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to list users.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

I've tried CURL (domain is changed for this msg):

```
curl --user "json_api:0hLL aIVn d8RB mR7Q 8R8H mICp" https://blog.thedomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users
```

I also tried POSTMAN following an example where someone had success. Subbed my credentials and url but still got the 401 error status.

Some more details:

For basic auth I'm using the account username (also tried email) and the application password with and without spaces.

The json_api user is set to administrator and I used a popular plugin to make sure the json_api user has all the roles it can possible have.

Htaccess file has the line

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

just after the rewrite engine line.

I've disabled "wordfence" and commented out the wordfence htaccess settings.

I notice the site is hosted on cloudflare but can't find any info on whether or not cloudflare makes a difference.

REST API is not a difficult thing, I make all sorts of integrations and have no problem with basic auth, but I've hit a wall with this one.

What have I missed?

Comment: Turns out this is a problem with Cloudflare. I had a chance to test my code out on a different WP installation and the basic auth worked fine. Have no idea what to do to make it work on cloudflare.

Comment: Did you actually figure out how to get it working with Cloudflare?